# Get result from sucess AJAX post and set HTML using globalEval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a Jquery function that posts data asynchronous

```
function post_data_async_globalEval(post_url, post_data, globaleval) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: post_url,
    data: post_data,
    dataType: 'html',
    async: true,
    timeout: 20000, // in milliseconds ~ 20 secs
    success: function (result) {
        jQuery.globalEval(globaleval);
    }
});
}
```

and i call it like that

```
post_data_async_globalEval("../Internal/RTV_COM?vid=1578", "type=TM", "$('#postinnerhtml').html(result);");
```

all i want is to execute this JS function

```
$('#postinnerhtml').html(result);
```

and replace the html of the response with the result variable that comes from the success function from the Ajax post request.

But i get this error when i execute the code

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: result is not defined
```

I could have added the JS code inside my success function but i don't want to use just one specific JS code, i just want to parse the JS code i want to execute after operation was successful.

Comment: Do you have to use `globalEval`? You might be successful if you set `result` in the success function to a global variable of the same name, but why not just allow the function to accept a callback function, rather than a string? The problem (I believe) is that your evaluated function is executing in the global context, not the success function context, so it cannot access variables local to the function in which it was evaluated.

Comment: how about just using eval instead of jQuery.globalEval?

Comment: Oh man i used eval and it worked :) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing a string as globaleval argument, you could pass a function:

```
function(result) {$('#postinnerhtml').html(result);}
```

And in the ajax call:

```
success: globaleval
```

(btw in this case you might also want to change the argument name...)

[Edit] To relay here my initial comment, you could also use the native eval() instead of jQuery.globalEval(). However eval() is usually considered evil when you accept input from an external source (here the result of an ajax call).

Answer (score 1):

You should be safe to just move your `$('#postinnerhtml').html(result);` inside `success: function (result) { }`, if you only want to replace the `#postinnerhtml` content with the response.
So will look like: http://jsbin.com/OGOgEnO/1/edit

Comment: Yes i know that, but the problem is that i don't send just this code to be executed, i can send any JS code to be executed